# Multiple nested if statements error: "Token Eof expected"

Tags: powerquery, m

I have the following code in PowerQuery and somehow I can't figure it out:

```
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "AKL" then "AKL" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "BCN" then "BCN" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "BOG" then "BOG" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "BOS" then "BOS" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "CDG" then "CDG" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "CUN" then "CUN" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "FCO" then "FCO" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "FRA" then "FRA" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "GIG" and [ARR_PORT_CODE] <> "AEP" or "EZE" then "GRU-BOND" else "GIG" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "GRU" and [FLIGHT_NO] >= 8000 or [FLIGHT_NO] <= 1400 then "GRU-BOND" else "GRU" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "GYE" then "GYE" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "JFK" then "JFK" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] "LAX" then "LAX" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "LHR" then "LHR" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "LIM" and [FLIGHT_NO] <= 2000 or >= 3000 then "LIM-ROW" else "LIM-LP" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] "LIS" then "LIS" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MAD" then "MAD" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MCO" then "MCO" then if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MDE" then "MDE" then if "MEX" then "MEX" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MXP" then "MXP" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "SCL" then "SCL" else if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "UIO" then "UIO" else 0
```

I need to do some filters in order to separate the treatment of the IATA codes according to the Flight number and the Arrival Airport.

I have revised the code many times, and as far as I'm new doing this I thing I'm a little blocked and can't see the solution as simple as it can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting into human-readable code makes the errors obvious:

1. **then** cannot be followed by **then**,
   see `if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MCO" then "MCO" then`
2. **else** cannot be followed by **else**,
   see `then "GRU-BOND" else "GIG" else`
3. comparing a column with text requires a condition,
   see `if [DEP_PORT_CODE] "LAX" then`
4. the column name has to be repeated in multiple conditions,
   see `if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "GIG" and [ARR_PORT_CODE] <> "AEP" or "EZE" then`

Besides that you could simplify the code by just listing the cases where [DEP_PORT_CODE]
is **NOT** returned and then putting [DEP_PORT_CODE] in the final else clause.

Here's your formatted code:

```
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "AKL" then "AKL" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "BCN" then "BCN" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "BOG" then "BOG" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "BOS" then "BOS" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "CDG" then "CDG" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "CUN" then "CUN" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "FCO" then "FCO" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "FRA" then "FRA" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "GIG" and [ARR_PORT_CODE] <> "AEP" or "EZE" then "GRU-BOND" else 
"GIG" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "GRU" and [FLIGHT_NO] >= 8000 or [FLIGHT_NO] <= 1400 then "GRU-BOND" else 
"GRU" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "GYE" then "GYE" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "JFK" then "JFK" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] "LAX" then "LAX" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "LHR" then "LHR" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "LIM" and [FLIGHT_NO] <= 2000 or >= 3000 then "LIM-ROW" else 
"LIM-LP" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] "LIS" then "LIS" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MAD" then "MAD" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MCO" then "MCO" then 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MDE" then "MDE" then 
if "MEX" then "MEX" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "MXP" then "MXP" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "SCL" then "SCL" else 
if [DEP_PORT_CODE] = "UIO" then "UIO" else 0
```

Comment: Another typical cause for the `Token Eof expected` error in PowerQuery if statements is not using lowercase, like IF .. THEN, but that isn't an issue here.

Comment: @mjmoralesf Did my answer help to solve your problem or are you still blocked?

Comment: In deed it helped, thanks a lot for your help, and I can't make enough emphasis in how much your phrase "Formatting into human-readable code" made sense to me. Thanks a lot.